# How do armor enhancements work?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've found some shiny new armor enhancement:
[image]

Now, when I try and drag this onto my armor, I'm getting the message "Action not allowed on this item". Am I doing it wrong, or can I only enhance certain armors, and not everything?

My questions now are:

- Can I enhance all armor part (also boots, trousers, gauntlets)?
- Does it only work for specific armors?
- Is it reversible?

Comment: +1 for the screenshot illustrating the awesome spelling of "fibre".

Comment: Or utterly mundane, depending on your location globally.

Comment: @Raven Canadians like me are deluged with American spellings.

Comment: @Matthew - for what it's worth, I think the Canadian/British spellings are cooler looking.

Comment: they appear early in the game for people who have imported their savegames and thus have raven's armor or for people with preorder dlc armor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The game manual states

> You can only upgrade those items that contain slots for runes and enhancements. When you own such a sword or armor and an upgrade, enter 
>   the equipment panel and drag the upgrade in question to a chosen item - 
>   it will be upgraded. You cannot undo an upgrade.

The upgrade slots appear as circles to the left of the item on the inventory screen. They are open if the slot is unused and filled if an enhancement is present.

[image: Sword with empty slot]

(This weapon has an empty slot)

[image: Armor with filled slot]

(This armor has been enhanced)

Answer (score 3):

According to the in-game help, you can only add enhancements to armor with an enhancement slot in the first place.

Near as I can figure, it's basically a version of the Diablo-esque socketing system, except instead of gemstones, you apply the enhancements instead.

(As to why they drop before you have armor with enhancement slots, who knows?)